# If a country house in England (1950) could not pay government death duties and is going to be demolished, what happens to the debt?

Tags: law

This grand English country house is going to be demolished. The owner owes death duties and debts. During the wars most of the valuable art etc were sold off to raise funds.  It was also requisitioned by the government in World War 2 for use as a convalescent home for wounded soldiers.  It is in a great state of disrepair. Despite being on the market for the past year. No one is interested in buying it.

But I don't know who pays for the demolition, (explosives etc) and what happens to the death duties, legally.

Comment: Hello and welcome to WorldBuilding! This looks like you are asking about the law in the real world. Maybe [Law.SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask such a question. We normally deal with imaginary worlds. Or am I misinterpreting your post? If so, what is the imaginary scenario you are trying to integrate this with?

Comment: This contains no hypothetical component, does not ask for any new creation, and is narrowly scoped to a very specific subject. Altogether, this question is off-topic for WorldBuilding SE.

Comment: Would a mansion like this actually be demolished, or just left to decay?

Comment: The owner would have to pay for demolition, if no one did it would remain a ruin and decay, as ikrase suggests. Take Witley Court for example http://www.english-heritage.org.uk/visit/places/witley-court-and-gardens/things-to-do/#Section1.

Comment: Had to look up death duties to find out it was mainly just inheritance tax. Also this really isn't the stack for this.

Comment: Helen, re-ask it on http://law.stackexchange.com .

Comment: It's fantasy/history. Character is summoned out of our time by fairies to England in 1947. But this question refers to the the history bit.  So thank you for the law links . I will consult them. Wiki and other sources confirm many UK mansions were demolished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Brit, and so may be way off base, but I suspect very strongly that demolishing the manor will do nothing to reduce death duties.

Such taxes are levied on the transfer of wealth from the deceased to his survivors. What the survivors do with it subsequently is up to them, but has nothing to do with the assessed value or tax liability. Certainly, if they choose to demolish the place that is their choice and they would need to come up with the money to do the job. By analogy, if you think your property taxes are too high and burn down your house, although the current value goes to zero last year's tax bill remains the same.

On the other hand, if they declare bankruptcy and turn the property over to the government in lieu of duties, the property becomes the responsibility of the government.

Comment: This might just be the answer. Declare bankruptcy and turn the property over to the government in lieu of duties. Then the property becomes the responsibility of the government and they can order and pay for the demolition. In one go it wipes clean his debt problem. And then the government can order something practical and dreary like a road or prison to be built .

Answer (score 2):

> The owner owes death duties and debts.

Owners don't owe death duties; estates do.  If there isn't enough money in the estate to pay the death duties, ownership would stay in the estate.  The government (owed the death duties) and the debtors would share ownership of the property.

> But I don't know who pays for the demolition, (explosives etc) and what happens to the death duties, legally.

In general, whoever orders the demolition pays for it.  It would be uncommon for demolition to be ordered without a subsequent plan for building on the property.  It's not impossible, just unlikely.  Demolition would be done for a reason.  Perhaps the building was considered dangerous and the government paid for it.  Or the government required the property owner to pay for it.  More likely they would demolish it in order to build something else:  a park, a mall, a roadway, whatever.

The death duties are paid out of the revenue from selling the property, as are the debts.  If there is not enough money to pay both, the government and the debtors negotiate a settlement.  Note that the death duties are owed on the equity of the property, after any mortgage.  If the heirs don't inherit anything, they don't pay anything.  If there is money left over, it goes back to the estate and then the heirs.

If there is an heir, that heir would not become an owner until *after* the death duties are paid.  If debts and death duties can't be paid out of the estate, the heir would have to buy the property out of the estate.  This could lead to a situation where the estate is selling the property to someone who will demolish the house.  But if the heir can generate enough money to buy the property, that can be avoided.  That could include a ruinously strict mortgage on the property.  You don't give many details about what kind of story you want to tell, but perhaps that can help get you where you want to go.

There may be further weirdness with taxes after that.  I'm not really sure where to ask for more information.  Law.SE would say that this is historical and doesn't apply to the current world.  History.SE may find it overly legal.  Obviously there are people here who don't view it as worldbuilding to ask about the actual historical world.  You could try asking where to ask on meta.History.SE.

Comment: The property has been in the family for 600 years thanks to hereditary privilege. The current heir/ owner is dying and only has months to live. He never married and has no heir. No one will buy the property due to damage from the war and general neglect. So I wanted the threat of demolition for dramatic tension. Who orders it and why is what I don't know. The law or history links are worth a try.